# load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc

Tags: android

I want use Material Design in my App， so I change AndroidManifest.xml just like：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.zdr.umarket" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

but when I running, Android Studio show:

```
05-07 14:33:01.478 21994-22007/com.zdr.umarket E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
05-07 14:33:01.496 21994-21994/com.zdr.umarket W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.zdr.umarket-1/lib/arm64
05-07 14:33:01.517 21994-21994/com.zdr.umarket I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
```

How do I?

Comment: I'm getting a very similar problem on a Huawei Honor 7.
Same app that crashes on Huawei, works perfectly on Xperia Z2.
Some testing I have done seems to point that the crash is due to attempting to access external storage when the user hasn't yet given this permission to the app.

Comment: Yes,my mobile is Huawei Honor 7,But I have added access to external access to the store,Although my application does not use external access to store permissions,The problem is still unresolved.@ak93