# Libgdx wallpaper not running on huawei y6ii

Tags: android, libgdx, huawei-mobile-services

I've been making a live wallpaper app for android. I'm using libgdx for the graphics. I've downloaded a test app from github. The app is running fine on most devices but not on my huawei. It crashes without exception as soon as the app is launched. I've surrounded all the working code with try catches but it cannot catch any exception so i'm guessing its not code related. I'll post the code i'm using just in case:

The application listener:

```
public class GDXTestPaper implements ApplicationListener {
public static float SQRT2;
// private ParticleEffect effect;
public int width, height;
public Vector2 touchPosition;
public Vector3 touchPosition3;
public ArrayList<Firefly> flies;
public ArrayList<Swarm> swarms;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture texture;
private int flyCount = 500;
// private MeshHelper meshHelper;
private int swarmCount = 5;
private boolean updateScreen = false;

@Override
public void create() {
    try {
        touchPosition = new Vector2();
        touchPosition3 = new Vector3();

        SQRT2 = (float) Math.sqrt(2);
        width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, height / width);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/firefly.png"));
        texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

        TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 64, 64);
        batch.enableBlending();

        batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        flies = new ArrayList<Firefly>();

        for (int i = 0; i < flyCount; i++) {
            try{
            Firefly f = new Firefly(this, region);
            flies.add(f);
            } catch (GdxRuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        swarms = new ArrayList<Swarm>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= swarmCount; i++) {
            try{
            Swarm s = new Swarm(this);
            swarms.add(s);
            } catch (GdxRuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (GdxRuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    texture.dispose();
    // meshHelper.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render() {
    try {
        // Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        // Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        if (Gdx.graphics.isGL20Available()) {
            Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
            Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        } else {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0.1f);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        }


        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        // Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        // Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        if (updateScreen) {
            updateScreen = false;
            camera.setToOrtho(false, width, height);
            batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
            // effect.setPosition(width/2, height/2);
        }
        camera.update();
        // effect.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()/1.6f);

        //Process touch
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            touchPosition3.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            camera.unproject(touchPosition3);

            touchPosition.set(touchPosition3.x, touchPosition3.y);
            //camera.unproject(touchPosition);
        } else {
            touchPosition.set(-1, -1);
        }

        batch.begin();
        // effect.draw(batch);

        // sprite.draw(batch);
        // batch.draw(texture, 10, 10);
        // batch.draw(texture, 50, 50);
        // batch.draw(texture, 100, 100);
        float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        for (Firefly fly : flies) {
            try {
                fly.move(delta);
                fly.render(batch);
            } catch (GdxRuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        for (Swarm swarm : swarms) {
            try {
                swarm.move(delta);
            } catch (GdxRuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        batch.end();
    } catch (GdxRuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    updateScreen = true;
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}
```

}

The main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = true;
        cfg.getTouchEventsForLiveWallpaper = true;

        initialize(new GDXTestPaper(), cfg);
        System.out.println("gdx initialized");
    } catch (GdxRuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The Firefly class:

```
public class Firefly {
public Vector2 position;
public Vector2 velocity;
public Vector2 acceleration;
public FireflyState state = FireflyState.ALIVE;
public boolean visible = true;
private float speedLimit = 60;
private float gravityForce = 6.2f;
private float alpha = 1f; // How bright are we
private Sprite sprite;
private GDXTestPaper stage;

Firefly(GDXTestPaper stage, TextureRegion region) {
    try {
        this.stage = stage;
        // Create sprite
        sprite = new Sprite(region);
        sprite.setSize(32f, 32f);

        // Origin central to sprite
        sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth() / 2, sprite.getHeight() / 2);
        // sprite.setPosition(100,10);

        Random rnd = new Random();

        // Init Position
        position = new Vector2(rnd.nextFloat() * stage.width, rnd.nextFloat()
                * stage.height);

        // Each firefly has randomly generated traits:
        speedLimit = rnd.nextFloat() * 30 + 10;
        // How attracted from a swarm
        gravityForce = rnd.nextFloat() * 10f;

        // position.set(rnd.nextFloat() * stage.width, rnd.nextFloat() *
        // stage.height);
        // position.set(30,50);

        // velocity = new Vector2(rnd.nextFloat() - 0.5f * 10,
        // rnd.nextFloat() - 0.5f * 10);
        velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        acceleration = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
    } catch (GdxRuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void create() {

}

void move(float delta) {
    try {

        switch (state) {
            case FADING:
                if (this.alpha > 0f) {
                    this.alpha -= 0.1f;
                } else {
                    alpha = 0f;
                    state = FireflyState.HIDING;

                }
                break;
            case GLOWING:
                if (this.alpha < 1f) {
                    this.alpha += 0.01f;
                } else {
                    alpha = 1f;
                    state = FireflyState.ALIVE;
                }

                break;
            case ALIVE:
                alpha = 1f;
                // Flyin' around minding our own business. Should we start fading?
                if (Math.random() > 0.999) {
                    state = FireflyState.FADING;
                }
                break;
            case HIDING:
                alpha = 0f;
                // We're flying around invisible at the moment. Should we light back
                // up?
                if (Math.random() > 0.999) {
                    state = FireflyState.GLOWING;
                }

                break;
            default:
                break;

        }

        // Should we turn on/off our light?

        acceleration.set(0f, 0f);

        acceleration.x += (float) (Math.random() - 0.5);
        acceleration.y += (float) (Math.random() - 0.5);

        // Screen edge bouncing
        if (position.x + velocity.x > stage.width - 2
                || position.x + velocity.x < 0) {
            // velocity.x = -velocity.x;
            velocity.x = 0;
        }
        // Screen edge bouncing
        if (position.y + velocity.y > stage.height - 2
                || position.y + velocity.y < 0) {
            // velocity.y = -velocity.y;
            velocity.y = 0;
        }

        velocity.add(acceleration);

        // Check touch gravity
        if (stage.touchPosition.x != -1) {
            // Active touch. Apply gravity, ignore swarms.
            float force = 10000 / this.position.dst2(stage.touchPosition);
            //this.velocity.x = force;
            //this.velocity.y = 0;
            //this.velocity.setAngle(angle)

            this.velocity.x += force
                    * (stage.touchPosition.x - this.position.x);
            this.velocity.y += force
                    * (stage.touchPosition.y - this.position.y);

        } else {

            // Gravity to swarms

            for (Swarm swarm : stage.swarms) {
                try {
                    float dist = this.fastDistance(swarm.position);
                    if (dist > 1 && dist < 200) {
                        float force = (gravityForce / dist) * delta;
                        this.velocity.x += force
                                * (swarm.position.x - this.position.x);
                        this.velocity.y += force
                                * (swarm.position.y - this.position.y);
                        // System.out.println(this.acceleration.x);
                    }
                } catch (GdxRuntimeException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        // }

        // If we start moving off the screen, strong force to push us back.
        if (position.x > stage.width || position.x < 0) {
            velocity.x = stage.width / 2 - position.x;
        }
        if (position.y > stage.height || position.y < 0) {
            velocity.y = stage.height / 2 - position.y;
            // position.y = stage.height / 2;
        }

        // Speed limiting
        if (velocity.x > speedLimit)
            velocity.x = speedLimit;
        if (velocity.x < -speedLimit)
            velocity.x = -speedLimit;
        if (velocity.y > speedLimit)
            velocity.y = speedLimit;
        if (velocity.y < -speedLimit)
            velocity.y = -speedLimit;

        // position.add(velocity);

        position.x += velocity.x * delta;
        position.y += velocity.y * delta;
    } catch (GdxRuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    try {
        alpha = Math.min(1f, alpha);
        alpha = Math.max(0f, alpha);

        if (state != FireflyState.HIDING) {
            sprite.setColor(0.5f, 1f, 0.5f, alpha);
            sprite.setPosition(position.x, position.y);
            sprite.setRotation(velocity.angle() - 90); // Texture rotated by 90
            // degrees
            sprite.draw(batch);
        }
    } catch (GdxRuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void dispose() {

}

float fastDistance(Vector2 target) {
    try {
        float abX = Math.abs(position.x - target.x);
        float abY = Math.abs(position.y - target.y);
        float dist = (float) ((1 + 1 / (4 - 2 * GDXTestPaper.SQRT2)) / 2 * Math
                .min((1 / GDXTestPaper.SQRT2) * (abX + abY), Math.max(abX, abY)));
        return dist;
    } catch (GdxRuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
}

public enum FireflyState {
    GLOWING, FADING, ALIVE, HIDING
}
```

}

The swarm class:

```
public class Swarm {
private static final float SPEED_LIMIT = 60;
public Vector2 position;
public Vector2 velocity;
public Vector2 acceleration;

private GDXTestPaper stage;


Swarm(GDXTestPaper stage) {
    try{
    this.stage = stage;


    Random rnd = new Random();

    // Init Position
    position = new Vector2(rnd.nextFloat() * stage.width, rnd.nextFloat()
            * stage.height);
    velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    acceleration = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
    } catch (GdxRuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void move(float delta) {
    try{
    acceleration.set(0f, 0f);

    acceleration.x += (float) (Math.random() - 0.5) * 8;
    acceleration.y += (float) (Math.random() - 0.5) * 8;

    // Screen edge bouncing
    if (position.x + velocity.x > stage.width - 2
            || position.x + velocity.x < 0) {
        // velocity.x = -velocity.x;
        velocity.x = 0;
    }
    // Screen edge bouncing
    if (position.y + velocity.y > stage.height - 2
            || position.y + velocity.y < 0) {
        // velocity.y = -velocity.y;
        velocity.y = 0;
    }

    velocity.add(acceleration);


    // }

    // Speed limiting
    if (velocity.x > SPEED_LIMIT)
        velocity.x = SPEED_LIMIT;
    if (velocity.x < -SPEED_LIMIT)
        velocity.x = -SPEED_LIMIT;
    if (velocity.y > SPEED_LIMIT)
        velocity.y = SPEED_LIMIT;
    if (velocity.y < -SPEED_LIMIT)
        velocity.y = -SPEED_LIMIT;

    // position.add(velocity);

    position.x += velocity.x * delta;
    position.y += velocity.y * delta;

    // Reposition on stage if we get lost
    if (position.x > stage.width || position.x < 0) {
        position.x = stage.width / 2;
    }
    if (position.y > stage.height || position.y < 0) {
        position.y = stage.height / 2;
    }
    } catch (GdxRuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The crash log:

I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
net.precariouspanther.gdxtest E/HAL:
load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc

> net.precariouspanther.gdxtest
>   I/BD.Reporter: com.huawei.bd.IBDService$Stub$Proxy@845e756
>
> net.precariouspanther.gdxtest
>   I/System.out: gdx initialized
>
> net.precariouspanther.gdxtest
>   I/AndroidInput: sensor listener setup
>
> net.precariouspanther.gdxtest
>   I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
>
> /net.precariouspanther.gdxtest E/HAL:
>   load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
>
> net.precariouspanther.gdxtest
>   I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>
> net.precariouspanther.gdxtest
>   W/OpenGLRenderer: load: so=/system/lib/libhwuibp.so dlopen failed:
>   library "/system/lib/libhwuibp.so" not found
>
> /net.precariouspanther.gdxtest
>   W/OpenGLRenderer: Initialize Binary Program Cache: Load Failed
>
> /net.precariouspanther.gdxtest E/HAL:
>   load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
>
> /net.precariouspanther.gdxtest
>   W/GL2JNIView: creating OpenGL ES 2.0 context
>
> /net.precariouspanther.gdxtest
>   I/AndroidInput: sensor listener tear down
>
> /net.precariouspanther.gdxtest
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26810 SIG: 9

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The 'real' error is the "E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc". I found 2 other threads discussing this error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585569/error-e-hal-load-id-gralloc-hmi-id-gralloc and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828725/load-id-gralloc-hmi-id-gralloc. It seems like it has something to do with Huawei phones.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. The issue was with the version of GL. I was randomly changing stuff and happened to stumble upon the part where i was setting useGL20 to true in the config. I changed that and the app is working. The errors in the log aren't related to the crash. They are still there but the app is working.